Running two Sessions at the same time in ASP.NET MVC 5 web app
The app must support multiple sessions so I want to use Session["username"] to store the username of logged user in each session. When I start the app I copy the link in another tab so I have two login tabs but when I log different users in those tabs, the Session["username"] is the same for both tabs (it contains the username of the last logged user).
I suspect that by copying the link to another tab I don't actually make another session but if that's the case, how do I make another session that works as I imagined?

I think what you actually have to do is to open the link in a different browser. Not just a different tab.

I fixed it by opening incognito tab so I guess it will also work with different browser, thanks!
